# how to update recyclerview when delete an item from adapter class

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

everyone, I am working with recycler view in android and I'm getting data from firebase. The problem is when I press the delete button data is deleted from firebase but in the application new list is added with the old list but I want to show only the new list which does not change the position of the recycler view only remove that item. I'm doing this all in the adapter class.

```
    final DatabaseReference referencePost = database.getReference().child("Posts").child(holder.postId);

  referencePost.setValue(null).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "" + Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        });
```

Comment: Show us the code that you are using.

Comment: I Didn't post code becouse I don't know the logic to handle this you can imagine a situation of a social media app in which we have a 3 dots in top right corner which contain a delete post option  and when I press that delete button how should I update the list after deleting the post now that list is repeating without the deletion post.

Comment: I added the code @AlexMamo you can check now

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: when I delete a post what exactly happening is the same list is concatenating with the old list but I want to show the newly updated list after removing the required item.

Answer (score 0):

After making sure that the **deletion process** from Firebase is complete, you can add this line:

```
.
.
//Successfully Deleted

notifyDataSetChanged ();
```

You can read about it more than [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter).